# React state behavior is not producing expected results

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I am controlling my navigation via useState like this:

```
const GameNav = () => {

    const [showGame, setGame] = useState(true);
    const [showCreation, setCreation] = useState(false);
    const [showScoresGame, setScoresGame] = useState(false);
    const [monsterChosen, setMonsterChosen] = useState(false);


    const handleGameClick = useCallback(e => { (setCreation(false) || setScoresGame(false)) || (setGame(true) && setMonsterChosen(true)) }, []);

    console.log("current monster testing: ", monsterChosen);   // why always false??


    return (
        <div id="app">

            <div id="navigation">
                <a className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={handleGameClick}>GAME</a>
            </div>

            <div id="pages">
                <div>  {showGame && <MainGame />}  </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );

}
```

The navigation is working fine.  When I click on a link, it goes to the appropriate page.

But I added another state item called "monsterChosen" that is set with "setMonsterChosen".

I set it to true when the link is clicked and it fires "handleGameClick".

Then I write it out to the console to see what it's current state value is.

But it always comes back as false...even though I set it to true in "handleGameClick".

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect `handleGameClick` to do? Cause its not doing whatever that is. State updaters are async function calls with no return, you can't conditionally chain them like that

Comment: `(setCreation(false) || setScoresGame(false)) || (setGame(true) && setMonsterChosen(true))` what are you doing here?

Comment: It will call all of the updaters until you get to the `&&` and then stop. I'm not sure what the goal is, but the solution is to re-write that function.

Comment: You are never calling `setMonsterChosen(true)` because all set* functions return `undefined` (those are `void` functions https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactInternalTypes.js#L311).

What is happening is: `undefined || undefined || (undefined && never) `

Could you describe better what needs to happen in `handleGameClick`?

Comment: @dobrinov handleGameClick is fired when the GAME link that shows  <MainGame /> component if showGame is true.  That part works...it's the 'setMonsterChosen' part that isn't working.

Comment: @BrianThompson why would it stop at the &&?  Because it is setting 'showGame' as true but not 'monsterChosen'

Comment: Because `setGame` does not return the value  of `showGame` it return nothing (`undefined`).

Comment: @BrianThompson Oh I see.  Thanks!  Changing the && symbols to II symbols fixed it!  Thank you!

Comment: But I don't think you're understanding the main issue. Why do you have `||` in the first place? None of your conditions will **ever** return anything other than `undefined`. Just remove the or operators altogether, they serve no purpose.

Comment: @BrianThompson do you mean remove them but then leave in all the setters? thanks

Comment: Yes. You may have to add `;` after each if you keep them inline.

Comment: @BrianThompson thanks again! :) Do I still need the useCallback(e => { command?